# How to go back to previous route in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

On early versions we can go back to **previous route** using **history**.

```
history.goBack()
```

How I can achieve that with **v6** of **react-router-dom**?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#use-navigate-instead-of-history Looks like it might be on `useNavigate`

Comment: This is great and all. How do you use the back and forward buttons of the browser? They are not detecting the previous route in the stack for some reason.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Try this approach

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function YourApp() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>go back</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have a question: If there is not prev page, how can I let it go to the home page please?

Comment: @PeterlitsZo use navigate("/")

Comment: @PedroCunha and how do you know that there is no previous page in history?

Answer (score 56):

in V6,

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
 
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-2)}>Go 2 pages back</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go back</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(1)}>Go forward</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(2)}>Go 2 pages forward</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is not supported in certain browsers though.

Answer (score 45):

**Update Dec 2023:**

It appears the history.state.idx method no longer works, currently this is doable with history.length, like the following:

```
if (window.history?.length) {
   router.back();
} else {
   router.replace(href || "/");
}
```

If you're supporting older systems it might pay to incorporate both like the following:

```
if (window.history?.length || window.history.state?.idx) {
   router.back();
} else {
   router.replace(href || "/");
}
```

**Original:**

Just in case anyone gets here like I did trying to navigate back OR navigate somewhere else if you can't navigate back (e.g. link opened in new tab), there doesn't seem to be any way of verifying the history with react-router in v6. *However* it seems you can access window.history.state which has an idx property that is zero if you're at the start of the history stack.

It's possible there are some gotchas around it that I haven't hit up against, but it's working for me:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

const navigate = useNavigate();

// ...

if (window.history.state && window.history.state.idx > 0) {
    navigate(-1);
} else {
    navigate('/', { replace: true }); // the current entry in the history stack will be replaced with the new one with { replace: true }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not 100% reliable. Take with a grain of salt. `window.history.state.idx` is not always defined, even when routing within the app.

Comment: @TaylorBuckner can you give an idea of what circumstances can cause it to be undefined? I've used it in several react apps and have yet to come across a scenario where it's undefined.

Comment: Heh guys, checkout my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78155780/18772048). It might be help you. I am not relying on window to check if we can navigate to previous page instead I am using `react-router-dom` `location.key`. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 19):

In old versions of react-router-dom there exists functions pop

you can reach them like:

```
const history = useHistory();
history.pop()
```

now in v6 you can use function useNavigate

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate(-1) // you will go one page back
navigate(-2) // you will go two pages back
```

Comment: 20 minutes of digging though the documentation and this magic number approach was nowhere to be found. Thank you

Comment: @DanielBaranowski pleasure that I can help you! :D

Comment: I guess they updated the docs as it looks like the magic number approach is listed there now... https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#usenavigate

Comment: Use `history.goBack()` instead of `pop()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar depends on which version you are using

Answer (score 10):

There is another way using a delta (number) in react-router Links v6 :

```
const BackButton = () => {
  return (
    <Link to={-1}>
      Back
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Unfortunately there is a type error in typescript, Link component does not accept numbers, but still it works.

Comment: Also works with NavLink: `<NavLink to={-1}>Back</NavLink>`

Comment: For anyone interested to use it with typescript: Instead of just `-1` you can write `-1 as any`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to navigate back or else where you can try this:

```
 <button onClick={() => navigate(-1) || navigate('/dashboard')}>
    Go back or Dashboard
  </button>
```

Comment: clever! do you know where in the docs can I reference this approach?

Comment: You can find usage of navigate(-1) in the v5 to v6 migration [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory) or in the [v6 docs here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

Comment: I don't think this works (`react-router-dom@6.4.2` here), because `navigate` returns `void`. I'm getting `An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.`

Comment: navigate(-1) returns undefined so this will always navigate to '/dashboard' (tested with react-router-dom 6.8.0)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that sometimes, there is a condition wherein navigate(-1) will lead to the wrong page such as for redirects during authorization check.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate(-1);
```

If we want to explicitly define a state where we have a previous page, we can add a "from" property in the state.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();
const currentPath = location.pathname;
navigate('/login', { state: { from: currentPath } });
```

Here before navigating to the login page, we set the routing state to have a "from" property which is equated to the current route.

When loading the page after logging in, we check first if there is a previous route stored in the state's "from" property much like the history stack with one level.

```
  const state = location.state;
  if (state?.from) {
     // Redirects back to the previous unauthenticated routes
     navigate(state?.from);
  else {
     navigate('/main-page');
   }
```

If the "from" property is falsy, then we navigate to a default page.

Again, this is a solution where we explicity define a previous route rather than than relying on the recent item in the history.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on window to check if we can navigate to previous page rather than just using React then checkout my solution. It works for me, I hope it will work for you as well.

If you want to check like can you navigate to previous page or not. There's an elegant solution:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Check if we can navigate back
  const canGoBack = location.key !== 'default';
  const href = canGoBack ? -1 : '/';

  return <Link to={href}>Some URL Content</Link>;
}
```

**Note**: The `location.key` value is always '**default**' on the initial location. This method utilizes the `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom v6`. Here, **-1** in the href means navigating to the previous page.

Checkout the [Library docs](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location.key) to learn more about `location.key`.

Answer (score -4):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";// react-router-dom v6 version 

const SecondComponent = () =>{
const navigate = useNavigate();
  
useEffect(() => {
    navigate('/secondComponent')
  },[]);

// note: we must have to to provide path like this one 
/*
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<FirstComponent/>} />
        <Route path="/secondComponent" element={<SecondComponent />} />
      </Routes>
*/

  return(
    <>
    <h2 >this is Second page</h2>
    </>
  )
}

export  default SecondComponent;
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. ```navigate('/secondComponent')``` navigate to another page. To go back you have to use ```navigate(-1)```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.