# Obtain the previous route in the URL - react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to find a way to obtain "previous" routes on a new page.

***Example:***

Suppose you have a route, `/profile` which can only be accessed if the user is authenticated. Also suppose that the user is currently on the route, `/contact` and they decide to access `/profile` in the browser url. I want the user to be redirected back to `/contact` since they are not authenticated.

I am using ***React*** with ***functional components***.

I have looked in various places for solutions, but most of the solutions posted on SO and the like are using `Link` elements or `useHistory` which to my knowledge is now deprecated.

I tried to use `useLocation` to do something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== '/profile') {
      setCurrentPath(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);
```

This in theory should update the pathname each time the url changes and prevent `/profile` to be the current pathname. However, I am getting an infinite loop still in the protected route component.

I'm sure there is a workaround this, but I haven't been able to find a viable solution.

Am I missing something crucial here?

Thanks.

***Edit:***

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948671/how-to-go-back-to-previous-route-in-react-router-dom-v6) solves my issue, however, the answer to my original problem has yet to be solved. (Obtaining the route from the previous page)

Now I'm left wondering, if this is even possible to begin with.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948671/how-to-go-back-to-previous-route-in-react-router-dom-v6

Comment: @MehmetDemiray Thanks, but I've seen that post already and that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Can you create small example on stackblitz?

Comment: Why don't you check auth before routing?

Comment: This is very good example for protected routes for v6.  Maybe you can do like this: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth

Comment: @MehmetDemiray Hey, I actually went back and tried it this solution. Though it wasn't what I initially wanted.. (I wanted the previous URL) But I guess this solution should suffice for now. Thanks.