# use navigate not working for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a back button with react

this is my function

```
<button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
```

But it is working only on the second click not the first one

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert with react but maybe you can try it like this.

```
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Back</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "useHistory" hook.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useHistory();

//call this method on button click
history.goBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-route-dom` v5 then you can do something like this.

By using this you can go back to the previous route added in history. Or it'll use `history.goBack()` by default.

```
            <button onClick={() => {
                if (history.location.state && history.location.state.prevRoute) {
                    history.push(history.location.state.prevRoute);
                } else {
                    history.goBack();
                }
            }}>
                 Back 
            </button>
```

Or you cna refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71647428/11045088) answer for v6.